# Why when Check if the user already exists in ASP.NET MVC database first not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I checked more than one post in this site and tried more than one solution but still I cannot check the user exist or not when register new user , I tried the following code :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult register(Registration reg)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userexist = db.Registration.Any(x => x.username == reg.username);
                if (userexist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("username", "User with this name already exists");
                    return View(reg);
                }
                else

                {
                    db.Registration.Add(reg);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }


            }
            return View();
        }
```

this is registration model :

```
namespace registration.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Registration
    {
        public int Userid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="ID or Iqama No ")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Medical Record Number ")]
        public int PatientNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile ")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Email Address ")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the view code and submit button there create button:

```
@model registration.Models.Registration

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register New User";
}

<h2>register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Registration Window</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" >
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = "0", @value = "0", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Login")
</div>
```

what is the missing in my code why its not working when click enter or tab or by mouse click its not checking ?

Comment: Does action hits the controller or not?

Comment: @Adlorem , I created the action register  in HomeController and then created the view from the registeration model.

Comment: Ok I understand but does the action from view hits the controller in debug mode? Did you try to catch for exceptions?

Comment: @Adlorem its working when create new account but its not validate when type the existing username  .

Comment: userexist is always false?

Comment: This is the point how to activate the action with tab or enter or mouse click i dont know how to do it , if userexist = true fire the validation ?

Comment: You want to fire the action when user enters data in view? Don' you have a form with submit button?

Comment: I added the view code there is submit button , how to link the action with username field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code correct and no errors , 
You said 
"when click enter or tab or by mouse click its not checking ?"

This code will work when you click the button Submit or Create . 
The code will validate the username exist or not and not when you navigate grom the username field.

Comment: OMG!!! , yes i am new to MVC and i didnt try to click create link , Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("register", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "LoginForm", @autocomplete = "off"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Registration Window</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" >
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "number", @min = "0", @value = "0", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult register(Registration reg)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userexist = db.Registration.Any(x => x.username == reg.username);
                if (userexist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("username", "User with this name already exists");
                    return View(reg);
                }
                else

                {
                    db.Registration.Add(reg);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }


            }
            return View();
        }
```